# Why aren't my turtles producing eggs?

Tags: breeding, turtles

I have two turtles, one male and another female, (I've identified the female by her more sloping back). There are 4 golden fish too in the tank with them.

It's been around 5 years since I brought them home, they were 3 inches in length from tail at that time and didn't have full grown nails (which were dirty white in color). Now their nails are fully grown and black, and they are both about 6 inches in length.

I was wondering that why there are no eggs yet? Did I wash them out during a water change when I was replacing the dirty water with new water? Could the water cleaner pump have sucked them out, or could the fish have eaten them? Is it not the right time, or could they have an improper diet? Please let me know how can I help them to conceive?

Comment: I volunteer with more than one rescue so I have to ask if you have asked yourself this question: If you have baby turtles, what will you do with them? If you keep the babies and they have more babies, than what?

Comment: I am not a turtle expert but arent turtles very affected by natural events and specific locations.  Like dont they only lay in basically the same place where they were born.  I dont know if that is all turtles or not but I have seen it on many documentaries about why losing shoreline is especially devastating to the turtle population.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've done anything specific to encourage egg-laying. Edit your question to add this detail. If you haven't done anything, then this is too broad and could be any number of reasons.

Comment: All responses were superb, but no answer yet. Actually, I am thinking, am I killing the fun in their life by forcing them to become a show piece inside my tank. I have a farm house, and a small natural pond of radius 12 feet, in there. Should I relocate my turtles there so that they can breed and enjoy life. But I am not sure there life is safe there. May be a bigger bird (or other)kill them. So what should I do?

Comment: @paul, your recent comment looks like it should be a separate question. You can use [this link](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to create a new question about housing your turtles outside.  You should indicate the general area you live in and the breed of turtles you have.

Comment: Question is still the same, I just prompted options, in my last comment, for some expert guy to choose/suggest(because I am not the one).

Comment: Note: http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5592/481